# What are problems so computationally difficult that they'll likely only be solved with quantum computers?

Tags: classical-computing, quantum-advantage, applications

Of course, there are the exceedingly well-known examples of this, eg. breaking RSI encryption, possibly protein folding, etc. What are some more obscure or overlooked ways that the greater computing power of quantum computers can be applied? What are problems that classical computers cannot handle but quantum computers could?

Comment: Well, one could prove tomorrow that $P=NP$; who knows!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1584/55. Or one of the many other related posts, eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2399/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/34004/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4169/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13513/55, and links therein